# Archiving data while running update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using sql server and I'm  trying to update certain columns in a table but before it updates the data, I want to insert the data into another table.

This is my code

```
declare @table1 table (Id int, Name varchar(100))
declare @temp table (Id int, Name varchar(100), CreatedOn datetime default getdate())

insert into @table1 values (1, 'Albert')
insert into @table1 values (2, 'Alex')
insert into @table1 values (3, 'Alas')
insert into @table1 values (4, 'Bob')

update @table1
set Name = 'B' + Name
output Deleted.Id, Deleted.Name, getdate() into @temp
where Name like 'A%'

select * from @table1
select * from @temp
```

Above code seems to be working correctly. Please let me know if I have to change anything.

Comment: Is this happening on a set schedule, or every time the data is being updated?

Comment: Not actually a schedule nor every time when data is updated... its a custom script. its executed when something bulk has to be deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change anything as long as the code performs what you need. If you want to insert records to another table on *every* update (and not only in this place) you should probably take a look at [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: actually I need this data only for this script... I so might not be going for triggers. thank you for the suggestion.